# How to pass grouped array to a table?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I Have grouped the array like below :

```
{
  "2023-10-01": [
    {
      "emp_id": 1,
      "name": "Aruna",
      "code": "DO",
      "date": "2023-10-01"
    },
    {
      "emp_id": 2,
      "name": "Aprilia",
      "code": "EVE",
      "date": "2023-10-01"
    }
  ],
  "2023-10-03": [
    {
      "emp_id": 1,
      "name": "Aruna",
      "code": "NIG",
      "date": "2023-10-03"
    },
    {
      "emp_id": 2,
      "name": "Aprilia",
      "code": "MID",
      "date": "2023-10-03"
    }
  ],
  "2023-10-04": [
    {
      "emp_id": 2,
      "name": "Aprilia",
      "code": "MID",
      "date": "2023-10-04"
    }
  ],
  "2023-10-05": [
    {
      "emp_id": 2,
      "name": "Aprilia",
      "code": "MID",
      "date": "2023-10-05"
    }
  ],
  "2023-10-06": [
    {
      "emp_id": 2,
      "name": "Aprilia",
      "code": "MID",
      "date": "2023-10-06"
    }
  ],
  "2023-10-07": [
    {
      "emp_id": 1,
      "name": "Aruna",
      "code": "DO",
      "date": "2023-10-07"
    },
    {
      "emp_id": 2,
      "name": "Aprilia",
      "code": "DO",
      "date": "2023-10-07"
    }
  ]
}
```

I would like to pass the grouped array to my table using Ajax. this is my expected table

| ID | 2023-10-01 | 2023-10-02 | 2023-10-03 | 2023-10-04 | 2023-10-05 | 2023-10-06 | 2023-10-07 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | DO |  | NIG |  |  |  | DO |
| 2 | EVE |  | MID | MID | MID | MID | DO |

Below is my JS code :

```
$.ajax({
    type: "get",
    url: "{{ route('schedules.fetch-table-schedule') }}",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (response) {
    $.each(response.result, function( index, value ) {
        var body= $("<tr><td>" + value + "</td></tr>");
        $("#schedule-table #body_schedule").append(body);
    });
}
```

Sorry, but I don't have any idea how to do it. Any help would be helpful for me. Thank you so much.

Comment: `I Have grouped the array like below :` could you possibly show the actual JSON - or what `response.result` actually is

Comment: @JaromandaX I updated the actual JSON.

Comment: oh, right so each property in the root of the result is a column in your table, and the `id` is the row - is that correct? Plus, there can be empty columns for dates not in the data - not as simple as a for loop, probably need a nested for loop

Comment: @JaromandaX Yes correct. I want to "emp_id" as a row (Probably will swap it with "name").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data needs a litte re-arranging then a possible solution could look something like this:

```js
let dates=[], names={}, start,end;
const data={"2023-10-01": [{"emp_id": 1,"name": "Aruna","code": "DO","date": "2023-10-01"},{"emp_id": 2,"name": "Aprilia","code": "EVE","date": "2023-10-01"}],"2023-10-03": [{"emp_id": 1,"name": "Aruna","code": "NIG","date": "2023-10-03"},{"emp_id": 2,"name": "Aprilia","code": "MID","date": "2023-10-03"}],"2023-10-04": [{"emp_id": 2,"name": "Aprilia","code": "MID","date": "2023-10-04"}],"2023-10-05": [{"emp_id": 2,"name": "Aprilia","code": "MID","date": "2023-10-05"}],"2023-10-06": [{"emp_id": 2,"name": "Aprilia","code": "MID","date": "2023-10-06"}],"2023-10-07": [{"emp_id": 1,"name": "Aruna","code": "DO","date": "2023-10-07"},{"emp_id": 2,"name": "Aprilia","code": "DO","date": "2023-10-07"}]},
 // reorganize data:
 obj=Object.entries(data).reduce((a,[k,arr])=>{
  arr.forEach(o=>{
    names[o.emp_id]=o.name;
    (a[o.emp_id]??={})[k]=o.code
  });
  if (!start || k<a.start) start=k;
  if (!end || k>end) end=k;
  return a;
 },{});
// interpolate a date range from data:
let curr=new Date(start), last=new Date(end);

// *** UPDATE ***
// set date range to all days of the months occuring in the data:
curr.setDate(1); // first day of the month
last.setMonth(last.getMonth()+1); // advance by one month
last.setDate(0); // last day of the previous month

for (;curr<=last; curr.setDate(curr.getDate()+1))
  dates.push(curr.getFullYear()+"-"
    +String(curr.getMonth()+1).padStart(2,"0")+"-"
    +String(curr.getDate()).padStart(2,"0"));
  
document.querySelector("table").innerHTML=
  "<thead><th>id</th><th>name</th>"+dates.map(d=>`<th>${d}</th>`).join("")+"</thead>"
 +"<tbody>"
 +Object.entries(obj).map(([id,o])=>
    `<tr><th>${id}</th><th>${names[id]}</th>${dates.map(d=>`<td>${o[d]??""}</td>`).join("")}</tr>`).join("\n")
 +"</tbody>";
```

```css
body {font-family:arial}
table {border-collapse:collapse}
tbody tr:nth-child(odd) {background-color:#eee}
td,th {border: 1px solid grey;
       padding:4px}
td {text-align:center}
```

```html
<table></table>
```

Since OP has changed their requirements in a comment (see below) I have updated my answer accordingly. Please try again ;-).

Comment: you don't handle "empty" dates :p

Comment: Now I do have these empty columns.

Comment: Hi @Carten, Thank you very much for helping me, but if I tried to put only single data in an array, your code only shows the date which has in the array. Do you know how to keep the date period (based on the period of the month)?  and also if I want to a new column after ID with name "Name" . Thank you in advance. I Very much appreciate it

Comment: I have updated my answer, but: Please keep your question in SO limited to _one issue_ and don't extend the scope of your question once it has been posted. Better: start a new question, focussing on this new aspect.